# Ubuntu 22.04, Nvidia HDMI audio not listed in sound settings, HP Omen 15, AMD R7 4800H, GTX 1650Ti

Tags: nvidia, sound, 22.04

Nvidia HDMI Audio not listed as output devices!
How do I get audio routed via HDMI?

[image: souns-settings]

```shell
aplay -l
```

[image: aplay]

Nvidia driver version 515.48.07
[image: nvidia-settings]

PRIME profile:
[image: prime-profile]

```shell
alsamixer
```

[image: alsamixer]

Comment: What does PRIME profiles say? If you have selected the iGPU then the Nvidia isn't being used.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, NVIDIA is selected. Added a screenshot as well!

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same laptop. And there were the same problems. After I

1. installed the old nvidia-driver-470 driver
2. pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload

everything worked. I don't know if point 2 is needed